# Wording of question caused confusion; how to correct it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked this question:

[I _____ a work of fiction. (Fill in the blank.)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264137/i-a-work-of-fiction-fill-in-the-blank/264150)

By "work of fiction", I meant "fictional story", or "fictional narrative", or "product of imagination that relates a series of connected imaginary events" -- you get the picture.

Most people answering and commenting on the question thought I meant "work of fictional literature". Consequently, the page is cluttered with discussion about the meaning of "fiction" rather than discussion of the word I am looking for.

How should I solve this problem? Ideas:

- Add text to the question body to clarify what I mean by the question title. (I have done that, but the page is still cluttered, and the question title still misrepresents the intended question.)
- Reword the question title. (The page would still be cluttered, and it would be even *more* confusing for someone who comes along later and sees all this irrelevant discussion about what a "work of fiction" is.)
- Ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You should edit your question (and possibly the title) to explain what your personal definition of 'a work of fiction' is. Otherwise, readers will use the normal definition, of a written work (which may of course include a screenplay or anything similar).

One word of warning, though; if (as I suspect) you mean "anything, in any medium or using any sense, that is not documenting facts", the question is likely to be closed as 'too broad'. You would need to explain *why* you think all such experiences can be described by a single word.

Comment: I too suspect the *real* question being asked by OP is "too broad", but it really needs to be much more clearly expressed. For example, would OP include *smelling* "lab-created" chemicals that fictitiously give the impression they contain extracts from certain aromatic plants (but actually are only similar to the real thing in terms of how they affect our senses)?